Redshift Query to count unique values based on name and process
QQ, I couldn't figure out how to solve the problem below.
I'm improving a query in redshift and need one more column to show the value Yes/No. I've the columns date, name, process and value, the values can be (L1, L2, L3, L4 and L5).
I need for the last date, check if there are two or more process for the same name with the value equal to L1 or L2, if so the result would be Yes, everything else No.
Is there a way to achieve that?

I'm improving a query ... where is the query?  You should include it in your question.

Please provide a set of sample input data and the matching output you would like to achieve. Also, please show us the code you have attempted and tell us the problem you are experiencing.
